# Is the browser-script-editor for monaco js example self-contained?

Tags: monaco-editor

I am following this example here: https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor-samples/blob/master/browser-script-editor/index.html

Would it work if I only have the files here included in my project?
Are the already distribution files.

Answer (score 0):

The referenced `loader.js` file will load other scripts, such as language definitions, which will fail if you don't provide it with all the files it tries to load.

My recommendation is, that you install Monaco via NPM or download the whole package and put it into your project's directory. This will save you a lot of time troubleshooting why Monaco is not working.